# Substitute newline in awk script for bash history printing w/timestamps

Tags: regex, bash, awk

I have recently switched on timestamps in my bash history. I am using three options to get more out of my history.

```
HISTTIMEFORMAT="[%F %T %Z] "; shopt -s histappend; PROMPT_COMMAND='history -a'
```

I cobbled together a bash script, rather than setting HISTSIZE to a ridiculously large number every time I want to look at history without having to brain-parse epoch time.

```
awk '/^#[0-9]+$/{ match($0,/[0-9]+/); 
    t = strftime("[%F %T %Z] ",substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)); 
    sub(/#[0-9]+/,t) } 1' ~/.bash_history | less
```

It's ugly, but it works. I imagine it could also be simplified, but that's only secondary to my reason for posting this. What I would like to do is prepend each command with its counterpart timestamp. I figured this can be done in `sub(/#[0-9]+/,t)`, but when I try to match the `\n`, it does nothing at all. What must I do to have it recognize the newline?

Any pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I for one don't understand what you're trying to do with `\n`. Just show us some sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your environment you may need to escape either with quotes or an additional backslash.

```
\\n   or "\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

The record separator `\n` is not part of the record `$0`.

You could modify your script slightly, so that it doesn't output the `\n`:

```
awk '/^#[0-9]+$/{ match($0,/[0-9]+/);
    t = strftime("[%F %T %Z] ",substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH));
    sub(/#[0-9]+/,t); printf $0; next } 1' ~/.bash_history | less
```